# Add custom language name to my Polylang dropbox menu and remove flags - using WordPress

Tags: wordpress, translation, polylang

I want to add languages name instead of flags in polylang dropbox menu. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [pll_the_languages()](https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/#pll_the_language) function and play with the different arguments. For your requirements, you could do something like this:

```
<!-- outputs a dropdown list of languages names -->
<?php pll_the_languages( array( 'dropdown' => 1 ) ); ?>
```

**UPDATE:**

If you use Widget for Language Menu, you can set these options there. Just go to **Dashboard > Appearance > Widgets**, expand the "Language Switcher" widget that has been added on the Sidebar and select the appropriate options.

Comment: Can you please tell me where I should add this?

Comment: Updated an answer.

Comment: I am using betheme and I did add the language switcher like you but the flags are not going from the main menu.

Comment: So the flags are already added in a theme, you just want to change the behavior?

Comment: Yes I just don't want flags on main menu.

Comment: If the language switcher is on the main menu, they are probably added in a template file. Maybe the code is in the header.php. If the language switcher is on a sidebar, they are probably added by using Widgets.